# Publish add-on on GSuite marketplace in "unlisted" mode

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, google-workspace, gsuite-addons

I have a GSuite add-on that I would like to publish only on the domains of my customers (who have GSuite accounts). From what I understand of the G Suite Marketplace:

- I can't put the Add-On Public because everyone on the planet will be able to install it
- I can't put it Private because I need users outside my domain to be able to access it

What would be the solution for this use case?

Comment: I suggest you to ask for experiences on the Google Apps Script community (see https://developers.google.com/apps-script) and to improve the wording to prevent this question be closed as "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: If you are publishing the add-on from your account, then it needs to published as public, but unlisted.  So, even though it's technically "public", if it's also unlisted, then the link is needed to find the listing in the Marketplace.  It's extremely unlikely that someone will randomly find the unlisted listing.  You could also check the email of the user and only allow certain users.  If you literally want to publish the add-on from their domain, then the code needs to be in a file in a Google Drive account of a user account in their domain.  So, they'll have access to it.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no official guide to publish and add-on for limited number of external domains.

While some services have a whitelist, this is not the case for G Suite Marketplace Add-ons and Editor Add-ons as of August 6, 2020.

So you will have to think that your add-on could be installed by anyone with a Google account but you could set something to limit it use.

Some alternatives:

G Suite add-on

- Set conditions to set the content to be shown on cards

G Suite Editor Add-on

- Set a dynamic custom menu
- Set conditions to set the content to be shown on dialogs and sidebars

Maybe the simpler solution will be to use the script properties to set a list of valid domains. To do this you could use `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` / `Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()` then something to get the user domain and compare it with your add-on's whitelist.

References

- https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-editor-addons
- https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/gsuite-publish-overview
- https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/gsuite-publishing-requirements

Comment: What do you mean by using the script properties to whitelist valid domains? Is it allowed by GSuite Marketplace?